# TypeScript error- This condition will always return 'false' since the types 'boolean' and 'string' have no overlap

Tags: html, angular, typescript, angular-ng-if

I am adding `ngIf` condition in `ng-container` where if the condition satisfies then `display the component`

The problem I am facing is I am getting error

```
 This condition will always return 'false' since the types 'boolean' and 'string' have no overlap.
```

When I set condition as  (When I use `not operator after &&`)

```
<ng-container *ngIf="data.dataClass === 'Dokes'
       && !data.dataSubclass === 'Land'"> ------------------>   NOT OPERATOR
```

But the code works fine when I remove the `!` operator in  `&& !data.dataSubclass === 'Land'`

I do not know why it is giving me the error. I want to add `!` operator as `I want to display component when data.dataSubclass is not equal to 'Land'`

.html file

```
  <div>
      <ng-container *ngIf="data.dataClass === 'Dokes' 
       && !data.dataSubclass === 'Land'">-----------------------------> ERRORRR

!----- BELOW IS THE COMPONENT TO DISPLAY IF ABOVE CONDITION IS TRUE---------!
          <money-property name="Pika" [model]="data.pika"
                    [editMode]="!!dataEditService.editMode">
      <dl>
        <dd *ngFor="let d of data.pika; index as i">
          <edit-link dataClass="Dokes" 
                     [(selectedElement)]="data.pika[i]" [editMode]="!!dataEditService.editMode"></edit-link>
        </dd>
        
      </dl>
    </money-property>
  </ng-container>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Adding `!` throws off the logic you're trying to implement because it'll negate the value *just to the right* of it. This:

```
&& !data.dataSubclass === 'Land'
```

is equivalent to

```
&& (!data.dataSubclass) === 'Land'
```

which of course doesn't make sense - a boolean won't ever compare to `'Land'`. You need:

```
&& !(data.dataSubclass === 'Land')
```

But a clearer approach would be:

```
&& data.dataSubclass !== 'Land'
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll try that, one more question what will be the good approach if I want to add one more condition `I want to display component when data.dataSubclass is not equal to 'Land' OR when not equal to Water`. One thing to `note` is `data.dataSubclass` can have one value at a time, it will be `Land` or `Water` for different records. I believe I should use `&&` operator, right?

Comment: `!['Land', 'Water'].includes(data.dataSubclass)`?

Comment: I am using Angular and the above code will be in html file

Comment: That shouldn't be a problem, should it? You can still use normal JavaScript inside `ngIf`

Comment: Aaha smart!! I thought it wont work. It did. Thank you